# How to deploy Vue with PM2

Tags: pm2

I have a vue3 + vitejs application that I would like to deploy on windows with pm2.

When I run the npm start myapp command, the status is in error.

Can you help me please?

ecosystem.config.js

```
name: 'myapp',
cwd: 'C:\myapp',
script: 'npm',
args: 'run dev'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the error. Secondly, you shouldn't be deploying your application through PM2. PM2 is normally used for backend node services. You're better off using IIS if you're on windows, building the application `npm run build`, and pointing IIS to the dist folder.

Comment: Thank you it works.
is there anything to do for accessing the file in the public folder because the path by default is : C:\myapp\dist\files\...
instead of C:\myapp\public\files\...

Comment: I copied the dist directory inside the public directory and in IIS instead of pointing to the "dist" directory I point IIS to the public directory. It works, I don't know if it's the best way.

Comment: I don't think there's any drawback for doing it that way. Doing it the other way (point to the existing dist folder) requires you to play around with folder permissions, whereas copying it over doesn't require that.